# Checking only certain values of an array for a Max threshold

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have a programm that is basically monitoring a temperature probe that has 9 channels. Out of these 9 channels 8 (sometimes 7) channels are CRUCIAL that they do not exceed certain temperature. I was writing a method as follows originally:

```
    public boolean isAverageGreaterThanMax(double max) {
        //return DoubleStream.of(values).allMatch(v -> v <= max);
        double averageValue = DoubleStream.of(values).average().getAsDouble();
        if (averageValue > max)
        {
            System.out.println("The Average of values is: " + averageValue + " The Max is: " + max);
            System.out.println("max met!");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

However this assumes all channels are going up at a similar rate, this is not true since I recently got a case where one channel was WAY WAY up and was skewing the entire average. 
I need to check that ALL CHANNELS (or 8 or 7) are above certain threshold, so I was thinking of something like this:

```
    public boolean isAverageGreaterThanMax(double max, int ch) {
        for (int i=0; i<ch; i++)
        {
            // CHECK ONLY AS MANY CHANNELS AS CH VARIABLE THAT WAS INPUTTED
            // IF ALL OF THE CHECK CHANNELS ARE ABOVE MAX TEMPERATURE RETURN TRUE
            // IF NOT THEN KEEP WAITING UNTIL ALL OF THEM ARE
        }
    }
```

But I can't seem to come up with what to do since i only want it if ALL OF THEM, however if I use an if loop then each one could return a true.
I hope i was clear, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need your program to check only when the function is called or Do you want it to check continuosly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you just check each one in turn. If any are below the max, return false, if none of them are below the max, return true.

```
public boolean isAverageGreaterThanMax(double max, int ch) {
    for (int i=0; i<ch; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] <= max) return false ;
    }
    return true ;
}
```

or, using streams:

```
public boolean isAverageGreaterThanMax(double max, int ch) {
    return DoubleStream.of(values).limit(ch).allMatch(v -> v > max);
}
```

Maybe I misunderstood the question, though.

Comment: This seems to the correct solution but I think that I also misunderstood the question. :P

Comment: I think that second one might be the key! Say I have a 9 element array, does limit(8) only check THE FIRST 8?

Comment: @DavidBoydston The first 8, as in your question, yes. (The first solution does exactly the same, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but maybe this helps you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] temperatures = new double[] { 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
    int minimalRequiredChannelCount = 3;

    if (DoubleStream.of(temperatures).allMatch(x -> yourRequirementCheck(x))) {
        System.out.println("all channels were fulfilling your requirement");
    } else {
        System.out.println("there was a channel not fulfilling the requirement");
    }

    long channelsFulFillingTheRequirementCount = DoubleStream.of(temperatures).filter(x -> yourRequirementCheck(x)).count();
    System.out.println(channelsFulFillingTheRequirementCount + " channels were fulfilling the requirement, min. required:" + minimalRequiredChannelCount);

    if (channelsFulFillingTheRequirementCount >= minimalRequiredChannelCount) {
        System.out.println("there were enough channels fulfilling the requirement");
    } else {
        System.out.println("there were NOT enough channels fulfilling the requirement");
    }

    double averageOfAllValidChannels = DoubleStream.of(temperatures).filter(x -> yourRequirementCheck(x)).average().orElse(-99999);
    System.out.println("the average temperature was:" + averageOfAllValidChannels);

}

public static boolean yourRequirementCheck(double temp) {
    if (temp > 55) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```